# Conditional Context Menu Triggers

Tags: c#, wpf

I currently have two buttons. One button is to Showappointments(), the other is ShowTask(). When either is clicked the FontWeight of that button goes to bold. Only one can be bolded at a time. I use that as the indicator to show which is being displayed.

The values are then displaye in a ListBox. I'm trying to have a condition such that when ShowTask fontweight is Bold it'll display the corresponding contextMneu for the Task, and it'll display a different set of contextmenus for Appointments.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredEventsCollection}"
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
             <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=AppointmentBold}" Value="Bold">
                       <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource Menu1}"></Setter>
                 </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 <StackPanel cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDoubleClick] = [Action Open()]">
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat=g}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Segoe UI"/>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company}" Foreground="Black"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

User Control Resources

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="TaskMenu">
    <MenuItem>Open This Task</MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
<ContextMenu x:Key="AppointmentMenu">
    <MenuItem>Open This Appointment</MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

This piece of code crashes right away, I'm wondering if I'm approaching correct and if I can get some guidance

Comment: What is the exception that you are seeing? Also where is Menu1 defined?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to rename Menu1 I'll update it to the correct corresponding. I changed it in my code forgot to change it here. The errors are here http://snag.gy/gd0HG.jpg doesn't quite make any sense to me.

Comment: It looks like the exception is being thrown when setting the itemssource and that would make me believe there is an InnerException you aren't seeing. It could be that it doesn't like StaticResource, you could try changing it to DynamicResource to quickly test. Failing that I would try removing parts of the xaml to find what the cause is.

Comment: When I remove the style it works fine. So I know the cause is around there. I shall look into DynamicResource

Comment: Or you could move the ContextMenu declarations into the ListBox.Resources and also place the Style in there